# Does Golang have LR(1) grammar?

Tags: go, grammar, lr-grammar, lr1

Does Golang have LR(1) grammar? In other words, can any Golang code be parsed by LR(1) parser? If yes, can we get this grammar rules?

The question is about the latest Go versions 1.20+

I have tried to find Golang grammar or grammar type for the latest versions but have not found anything

Comment: The Go language requires arbitrary lookahead. You can find the original LALR(1) bison code in early versions of the go source.